# get full class name from short class name

Tags: php, reflection, autoload

Somewhere in the codebase there is a file abc.php with a class named abc:

```
<?php
namespace x\y\z;

class abc {
    // ...
}
```

In different script, a variable with short class name (without namespace):

```
$className = "abc";
```

I need a reflection of class, but the code:

```
  $r = new \ReflectionClass($className); //Error: Class abc does not exist in...
```

is not working since full class name `"x\y\z\abc"` is required.

Building an object also not working for the same reason:

```
$obj = new $className(); // Error: Class 'abc' not found in...
```

How to find the full class name from the short one ?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: How is the calling code supposed to know which namespace to use? If you also had a class named `abc` in namespace `j\k\l` then which one would it load?

Comment: @iainn assuming that the short class name is unique

Comment: At that point you'd need to traverse all files under the application root to find `abc.php`, and then extract the namespace either from the directory structure or by parsing the file itself. This sounds like quite a strange problem to have though - why do you only have the short class name available when reflecting?

Comment: this is because, i have the object was stored in a table, and the table name is class short name